# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, client

I'm just trying to get simple email/password authentication working. As a test, trying to just create users. It's not working, when clicking the button to pass some hard-coded email/password vars to auth, I get this console error below. As far as I understand I should be able to do this from client-side without having to set up any server. I also have firebase email/password authentication enabled in firebase console.

```js
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 87795057294 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=87795057294 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=87795057294"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 87795057294 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=87795057294 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

Though I did check and Google Identity Toolkit API is enabled

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Firebase Auth Test</title>

    <!-- Firebase JavaScript Link -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- JQuery -->


    <!-- ================================================================================== -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Initialize Firebase
            // This is the code we copied and pasted from our app page
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyBJOZIBC9J3MUfkLfXGKgvaNYxilplQ7fI",
                authDomain: "project1-e7460.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://project1-e7460.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "project1-e7460",
                storageBucket: "project1-e7460.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "87795057294"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);

            var email = "geochanto@yahoo.com";
            var password = "Abc1234!";

            // Get a reference to the database service
            var database = firebase.database();
            var clickCounter = 0;

            $("#clickme").on("click", function() {
                console.log('clicked!');

                clickCounter++;
                database.ref().set({
                    clickCount: clickCounter,
                    em: email,
                    pa: password
                });

                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // ...
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
    <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is related but make sure `Token Service API (securetoken.googleapis.com)` is also enabled.

Comment: @bojeil yep, it is enabled.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @geochanto did you find the solution ?

Comment: this was a long time ago... I did solve it but at this point don't remember how.

Answer (score 2):

You need to login to your Firebase Console and enable the Sign-In Method.

See the point 3 of the [Before You Begin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#before_you_begin) section in the Authentication documentation.

> Enable Email/Password sign-in:
>
> In the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com), open the **Auth** section.
>   On the **Sign in method** tab, enable the **Email/password** sign-in method and click **Save**.

Then try again - it should work once enabled.

Comment: I have it enabled :) forgot to include that in the description.